# McDonald's app showing "Your device did not pass our security check ..."

Tags: applications, security, application-error

A client came to fix his phone because it is receiving this message when he opens the recently installed "McDonald's" app:

> Your device did not pass our security check. Please check that you run a Google trusted OS version, that the device is not rooted and that you have no harmful apps installed

Curiously the phone is not rooted, and is also a modern and updated Samsung phone.

What could be the issue? solutions?

Comment: Most likely the app has used Google SafetyNet check. There are apps in PlayStore which also use this test and show the detailed result.

Comment: Known issue: [Reddit - McDonalds app not working](https://www.reddit.com/r/Huawei/comments/orww8n/mcdonalds_app_not_working/), [HardwareZone - Redmi Note 9](https://forums.hardwarezone.com.sg/threads/redmi-note-9.6220376/post-130118775), [HardwareZone - Huawei Mate 30 Series](https://forums.hardwarezone.com.sg/threads/huawei-mate-30-series.6102322/post-124278711), [Zwame - Xiaomi Mi 9T / 9T Pro (Redmi K20 / K20 Pro)](https://forum.zwame.pt/threads/xiaomi-mi-9t-9t-pro-redmi-k20-k20-pro.1033223/post-16284425) (Portuguese), [App complaints](https://www.sikayetvar.com/mcdonalds/device) (Turkish)

Answer (score 1):

Try to run a safety net test on the device. Check if  they have a custom recovery, or if the bootloader is unlocked. If it is Samsung, check if Knox is triggered. How do you know it is not rooted? In what way did you check?

Comment: Also, what device is it? If it is Samsung, check if Knox is triggered.

Comment: How do you know it is not rooted? In what way did you check?

Comment: You should integrate your comments into your answer.